# Change font size of source code in org-reveal export

Tags: org-mode, reveal.js

I have an org file with shell source code (but this happens also with python) that should be part of a reveal.js presentation.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
  > ls -la
#+END_SRC
```

This code should not be evaluated, only shown in the presentation.

The source code is shown but it is very small. How can I change the font size of the source code?

And something else happens in the html file

The output shows these symbols:

```
ls -la
```

The html file of this line shows this

```
<pre  class="src src-shell">
&gt; ls -la&#57344;&#57345;&#57345;
...
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer myself. The font size of the source code can be modified by an additional CSS file.

In the org file:

```
#+REVEAL_EXTRA_CSS: ./modifications.css
```

In modifications.css

```
.reveal pre {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

I have no clue about this strange symbols, could not reproduce them on another installation.

Comment: But how to change only one particular element style? I mean, how to add inline css!?

Comment: OK. I used the ```#+name``` attribute and in the modifications.css I reference the pre#MYID ! Thanks

Comment: Gah, two years later but I'm getting the same three symbols! They're really hard to search in Google, but I found this *one* match when searching SO for "57344 org-mode".

Comment: Follow-up: this [github issue comment](https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator/issues/45#issuecomment-108911964) has a workaround.

Answer (score 11):

I know this already has an accepted answer, and this post is approaching 3.5 years old, but I wanted to share the simple solution I used. Just wrapping the `src` block within a `div` using `#+REVEAL_HTML`, and specifying the `font-size` within the `style` does the trick.

(The CUDA code within the `src` block is just an example)

```
  #+REVEAL_HTML: <div style="font-size: 60%;">
  #+BEGIN_SRC cpp
template <typename data_type, op_type op> __global__ void stream_thread(data_type *ptr, const size_t size, data_type *output, const data_type val) {
    size_t tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    size_t n = size / sizeof(data_type);
    data_type accum = 0;

    for (; tid < n; tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
      if (op == READ)
          accum += ptr[tid];
      else
          ptr[tid] = val;

    if (op == READ)
        output[threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x] = accum;
}
  #+END_SRC
  #+REVEAL_HTML: </div>
```